# Error when trying to join a table and a stream

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to join a table and a stream and create another table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE table_fx_latest AS
   SELECT t1.currencyid,
          t1.maxtimestamp,
          t2.midprice 
  FROM stream_fx2 t2 LEFT JOIN table_fx_latest3 t1 
  ON t1.currencyid = t2.currencyid AND 
     t1.timestamp = t2.maxtimestamp 
  GROUP BY t1.currencyid, 
           t1.maxtimestamp, 
           t2.midprice;
```

but the following error is reported:

```
Cannot RUN execution plan for this statement, CreateTableAsSelect{name=TABLE_FX_LATEST_PRICE6, query=Query{queryBody=QuerySpecification{select=Select{distinct=false, selectItems=[T1.CURRENCYID T1_CURRENCYID, T1.MAXTIMESTAMP MAXTIMESTAMP, T2.MIDPRICE MIDPRICE]}, from=Join{type=LEFT, left=AliasedRelation{relation=STREAM_FX2, alias=T2}, right=AliasedRelation{relation=TABLE_FX_LATEST3, alias=T1}, criteria=Optional[JoinOn{((T1.CURRENCYID = T2.CURRENCYID) AND (T2.TIMESTAMP = T1.MAXTIMESTAMP))}]}, =null, where=null, groupBy=Optional[GroupBy{isDistinct=false, groupingElements=[SimpleGroupBy{columns=[T1.CURRENCYID]}, SimpleGroupBy{columns=[T1.MAXTIMESTAMP]}, SimpleGroupBy{columns=[T2.MIDPRICE]}]}], having=null, orderBy=[], limit=null}, orderBy=[]}, notExists=false, properties={}}
Caused by: io.confluent.ksql.parser.tree.LogicalBinaryExpression cannot be cast to io.confluent.ksql.parser.tree.ComparisonExpression
```

And here's the description for both `stream_fx2` stream and `table_fx_latest3` table:

```
ksql> describe stream_fx2;

Field      | Type
----------------------------------------
ROWTIME    | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY     | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
ID         | INTEGER
CURRENCY   | VARCHAR(STRING)
CURRENCYID | INTEGER
TIMESTAMP  | BIGINT
BIDPRICE   | DOUBLE
MIDPRICE   | DOUBLE
OFFERPRICE | DOUBLE

ksql> describe table_fx_latest3;

Field        | Type
------------------------------------------
ROWTIME      | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY       | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
CURRENCYID   | INTEGER          (key)
MAXTIMESTAMP | BIGINT
------------------------------------------
```

I guess that this might be a bug of KSQL (still in developer preview) but I wanted to make sure that I am not missing anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JOIN` criteria should only be key equality. If you have any other criteria you need to put them in the `WHERE` clause. 
Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table_fx_latest AS
  SELECT t1.currencyid,
         t1.maxtimestamp,
         t2.midprice 
  FROM stream_fx2 t2 LEFT JOIN table_fx_latest3 t1 
    ON t1.currencyid = t2.currencyid
  WHERE 
    t1.timestamp = t2.maxtimestamp 
  GROUP BY t1.currencyid, 
           t1.maxtimestamp, 
           t2.midprice;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: The table is created successfully but I get an Exception: 
`Error Serializing Avro message` which is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Comment: Can you check to make sure you define the schema for the source stream and table correctly. Seems that one of the fields is not defined with the right type.

Comment: I have been using a field which was `float` so I've created some new tables and streams with `double` instead. But some new issues appear. Could you please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785805/null-rowkey-in-a-stream and shed some light?