# KSQL Multiple Column Join - LogicalBinaryExpression cannot be cast to ComparisonExpression

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am investigating some things for work where we have to prove the value of Kafka and KSQL as part of a POC. We are working on simple game events where a player can make a play and the game engine either assigns them points (considered a win) or they get nothing (considered a loss). One of our requirements is to prove the feasibility of KSQL on consecutive losses or wins. 
*For the purposes of this question, I will focus on consecutive losses.*

We have two tables, one for wins and one for losses that run against the same stream of game events.

The wins DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS AS
    SELECT  userId,
            gameName,
            COUNT(*) AS totalWins
    FROM STREAM__GAME_EVENTS
    WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 30 MINUTES)
    WHERE pointsAllocated > 0
    GROUP BY    userId,
                gameName;
```

The losses DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__LOSSES AS
    SELECT  userId,
            gameName,
            COUNT(*) AS totalLosses
    FROM STREAM__GAME_EVENTS
    WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 30 MINUTES)
    WHERE pointsAllocated = 0
    GROUP BY    userId,
                gameName;
```

In order to achieve consecutive losses in the 30 minute window period, our current approach is to `JOIN` the `WINS` table onto the `LOSSES` table and only fire when there is nothing in the `WINS` table and something in the `LOSSES` table.

To do that, we have the following code:

```
SELECT  losses.userId,
        losses.gameName,
        losses.totalLosses
    FROM TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__LOSSES losses
        JOIN TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS wins
            ON wins.userId = losses.userId
            AND wins.gameName = losses.gameName
    WHERE losses.totalLosses >= 1
        AND wins.totalWins = 0;
```

When I try to execute that code I get the following error:
`io.confluent.ksql.parser.tree.LogicalBinaryExpression cannot be cast to io.confluent.ksql.parser.tree.ComparisonExpression`

Initially I thought it was to do with the `WHERE` clause but after looking at [Hojjat's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753589/5837098), it appears to be that the issue has to do with the `AND` statement in the `JOIN`.

When I ran `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` on both tables I get the following (same for both):

```
ksql> DESCRIBE EXTENDED TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS;

Name                 : TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS
Type                 : TABLE
Key field            : KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_0|+|KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_1
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS (partitions: 4, replication: 1)

 Field     | Type
---------------------------------------
 ROWTIME   | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 USERID    | INTEGER
 GAMENAME  | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TOTALWINS | BIGINT
---------------------------------------
```

Given that `COL_0` - `userId` and `COL_1` - `gameName` are the key fields on both tables, it seems logical that they *have* to be included in the `JOIN`. Is it possible to get around this or is it currently not possible to `JOIN` on multiple columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple expressions in your `ON` clause; you can only have one.

Try moving one of them into your `WHERE` clause instead:

```
SELECT  losses.userId,
        losses.gameName,
        losses.totalLosses
    FROM TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__LOSSES losses
        JOIN TABLE__GAME_EVENTS__WINS wins
            ON wins.userId = losses.userId
    WHERE   wins.gameName = losses.gameName
        AND losses.totalLosses >= 1
        AND wins.totalWins = 0;
```

Comment: I gave this a try and got the following respone:

`Source table (LOSSES) key column (KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_0|+|KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_1 is not the column used in the join criteria (USERID).`

Comment: What version of KSQL are you using?

Comment: We are using KSQL 5.2.1.